Can I include Google OAuth client secret in my desktop app?
I would think the answer is "NO!!" and it seems google agrees. "Installed apps are distributed to individual devices, and it is assumed that these apps cannot keep secrets" from from google's docs. Unfortunately, they still require the client token to do anything with. Is the assumption that even if they are exposed it will not be an issue?

The oauth client secret is required for authentication with a desktop app.
There for you must have it somewhere
I have seen several solution to try to keep it secure none are perfect
First include it in your app so it will be compiled within your app.
Two have it on an encrypted api endpoint on your server and require the app request it.
What ever you do don't store it in clear text in a directory on the users machine

This is interesting. I was hoping google would have disclosed a best practices somewhere or to someone and I just could not find it. Putting it in a compiled app is basically useless as it can easily be extracted. Unfortunately, using an API endpoint is not a possibility for this app.
